# How to send an array from node.js and render it in .ejs file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

This is my first time for using ejs&node.js...

My goal is sending an array and making an imgBox element for each element.

Here is my node.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
const sqlite = require('sqlite');

const app = express();
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views','./views');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

async function getDBConnection(){
    const db = await sqlite.open({
        filename : 'product.db',
        driver: sqlite3.Database
    });
    return db;
}

app.get('/', async function(req,res){
    let db = await getDBConnection();
    let rows = await db.all('select * from items');
    await db.close();   
    
    var output=new Array();

    for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
        output.push(rows[i]['product_title']);
    }
    
    res.render('index',{
        test: "ㅇㅇ ",
        title: output
    });
});

var port = 3000;
app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log('server on! http://localhost: '+port);
});
```

and here is my .ejs code where I want to make elements from an array(in this case, the array named as 'output'.):

```
            <div id="itemBox">
                <% var len = title.length; %>
                <% for(let i=0;i<len;i++){ %>
                    <div id="imgBox"><%=title[i]%></div><br>
                <% } %>    
            </div>
```

What I wanted is making (len) imgBox elements by array's elements, but the thing displayed on the screen was only string...

Could you please teach me how to deal with an array in node.js and ejs file?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use built-in express.json() and express.urlencoded() methods instead bodyParser.

Comment: ids should be unique, but you're making `n` of the same id. Use a class. The EJS loop looks OK to me though.

Comment: try parsing the array in ejs as JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrayname)) and then use it, also instead of simple for loop you can use forEach loop to work with all elements in array